# log4j - DailyRollingFileAppender, override subAppend()

Tags: log4j

I am new to log4j's DailyRollingFileAppender class and I would like to use this to perform daily rotation of the log file and at the same time would like to also manually modify the log file every time there is an event triggered to log event.

For example, I would like to always increment the value by one for "TOTAL COUNT:" inside the log file. How can I go about doing that?

Example of the log content:

```
07 Oct 2011 16:57:51 [INFO ] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:51 [WARN ] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:51 [ERROR] - Successful
07 Oct 2011 16:57:51 [FATAL] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:52 [DEBUG] - Successful
07 Oct 2011 16:57:52 [INFO ] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:52 [WARN ] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:52 [ERROR] - Successful
07 Oct 2011 16:57:52 [FATAL] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:53 [DEBUG] - Successful
07 Oct 2011 16:57:53 [INFO ] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:53 [WARN ] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:53 [ERROR] - Successful
07 Oct 2011 16:57:53 [FATAL] - Failed
07 Oct 2011 16:57:54 [DEBUG] – Successful

TOTAL COUNT: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems overriding `subAppend()` in the `DailyRollingFileAppender` is the way to go. You'll also have to be cautious when calling `super.subAppend()`, as the `WriterAppender` implements it like this:

```java
protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
    this.qw.write(this.layout.format(event));
    // ...
}
```

and you don't want layout with your "TOTAL COUNT" line.

In my `subAppend()` I'd copy exactly what D.R.F.Appender does, adding:

- line counting logic, if not present elsewhere,
- a condition checking if a special line should be printed, then formatting and printing it directly to `qw`.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part saying "and you don't want layout with your "TOTAL COUNT" line.". Does "this.qw.write(this.layout.format(event))" write a new log event to the file or append to the end of the file?

Comment: @mike And what is the difference between these 2 options? Log lines are always appended, you cannot put anything in the middle. By "don't want layout [...]" I meant, if you logged "TOTAL COUNT" normally, you'd get a line like "07 Oct 2011 16:57:54 [DEBUG] TOTAL COUNT", as in your example - that's why you need to bypass the formatter.

Comment: If it's always log in an appended manner, I'm guessing the only way to modify a line in the middle is to open the log file manually and perform a search and replace to the string in the file?

Comment: @mike Yes - manual correction, or the way I described in the answer. DO NOT, however, modify a live file in another process, only the files that log4j finished writing to.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I think my situation is that I need to modify the log file that is still logging. So, I suppose I need to come up with something else to show the total count. Maybe introducing a field in the log to show the row number, something like "No. 534 
07 Oct 2011 16:57:51 [ERROR] - Successful"?

Comment: @mike It's up to you now - do what you need to do. This starts drifting away from the original question, and SO does not really work well as a forum. Oh, BTW, there's a built-in mechanism for saying "thanks" on SO, and that is Mr Voting Button and Mr Accept Button, left of the post ;-)